# Объединение строк таблицы

Tags: mysql

Помогите, пожалуйста, с SQL запросом: нужно объединить поля message для записей, у которых совпадают поля ref в такой примерно таблице:

```
+----+-----------------+-------------+-----+
| id | message         | date        | ref |
+----+-----------------+-------------+-----+
| 07 | first message   | 2018-03-11  |  12 |
| 08 | second message  | 2018-03-14  |  2  |
| 09 | another message | 2018-03-05  |  2  |
| 10 | first message   | 2018-03-07  |  8  |
```

остальные поля - несущественны, можно скопировать любое из объединяемых строк.

Результат должен выглядеть так:

```
+----+-----------------+-------------+-----+
| id | message         | date        | ref |
+----+-----------------+-------------+-----+
| 07 | first message   | 2018-03-11  |  12 |
+----+-----------------+-------------+-----+
| 08 | second message  | 2018-03-14  |  2  |
|    | another message |             |     |
+----+-----------------+-------------+-----+
| 10 | first message   | 2018-03-07  |  8  |
```

СУБД - MySQL 5.5

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT MIN(id) id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(message ORDER BY id SEPARATOR '\n') message,
       MAX(`date`) `date`,
       ref
FROM sourcetable
GROUP BY ref
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Работает!